# Define inlet temperature in multi-stage adiabatic reactor

Tags: chemical-engineering

While solving some exercises for an exam, I faced a problem with a two-stage adiabatic reactor, producing methanol (exothermal reaction), with intermediate cooling. Both stages achieve equilibrium.

Two of the questions were:

1. Inlet temperature at the second stage
2. Load at the intermediate cooling exchanger

I have the inlet temperature in the first reactor, so I can couple a heat balance and a mass balance to obtain the temperature at the outlet of the first stage.

**How do I calculate the inlet temperature at the second stage?**

My first idea has been to suppose it equal to the first inlet temperature, but I cannot find any evidence to back it up. On the contrary, multiple charts have shown the inlet temperatures increasing after each stage. How else can I obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem out of Fogler. I would assume it's the same as the first stage. There is no way to calculate it seeing as you must find the load of the heat exchanger. One of those two variables must be specified to get the other one, so if they don't give the inlet temperature you have to assume it. Not sure what charts your talking about. Hope this helps.

Comment: It might as well be, adapted to be a question on the state exam. 
I know these two variables are related, and this is why I was having such a difficult time calculating either one and wanted to make sure that my assumption was plausible. 
P.S. from Italy?